# If projected Covariance matrix is the zero map, how do I show the projection takes all observations to the same point?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, covariance

Say I have the, covariance matrix $\mathbf{S}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(\mathbf{x}_{i}-\boldsymbol{\mu}\right)\left(\mathbf{x}_{i}-\boldsymbol{\mu}\right)^{T}$

and a set of basis vectors $\mathbf{u}_{j}$ in a matrix $\mathbf{U}=\left[\mathbf{u}_{1}, \ldots, \mathbf{u}_{d}\right]$

How do I proove:

If  $\mathbf{U}^{T} \mathbf{SU}=\mathbf{0}$ prove that $\mathrm{U}$ projects all observations $\mathrm{x}_{i}$ to the same point, i.e. $\mathbf{U}^{T} \mathbf{x}_{i}=\mathbf{U}^{T} \mathbf{x}_{j}$ for all $i, j$

---

I'm a bit stuck with this, I know it is probably obvious.

My attempt is to write S as  $\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{\overline{X}} 
  \mathbf{\overline{X}^{T}}$ and $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{U}^{T}\mathbf{\overline{X}}$ the projection. $\mathbf{U}^{T} \mathbf{SU}=\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^{T}= \mathbf{0}$
So therefore this projected covariance matrix is completely degenerate , so there is no information from this projection. But I don't get how to show the above.

Does $\mathbf{U}^{T} \mathbf{x}_{i}$ = 0 vector, for every i?

Comment: I think you would get $\boldsymbol{U}^T \boldsymbol{x}_i= \boldsymbol{U}^T \boldsymbol{\mu}$ and then $\boldsymbol{U}^T \overline{\boldsymbol{x}}_i=0$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: what do you say $U$ 'projects'? is it true that $U^TU = I_d$? and what is the dimension the vectors $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf u$?  Saying $U$ has a set of basis vector makes it sound like it is invertible....

Comment: yes that's right. U is orthonormal basis. ah, this is in the context of PCA. so u and x have same dimensions say n. U is n x d matrix

Comment: Ah sorry, i got the notation wrong, it should be u and x both have F dimensions. and yes this probelm is geared  to consider F >> N, so X is not square, so S is not invertible, but full rank for non square matrix.  so X is F x N matrix, S is rank(N), or more technically rank(N-1) because minus a degree of freedom for the mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you let $y_i=U^T x_i$, then $U^T S U = \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i-\nu)(y_i-\nu)^T$ where $\nu$ is the mean of the $y_i$s (which is exactly $U^T \mu$). This means that the covariance of the $y_i$ is $0$.

So your statement is true whenever the following is true :

> If $S=0$ prove that $x_i=x_j$ for all $i$, $j$.

The fact that $S_{j,j}=0$ implies that $\sum_{i=1}^N (x_{i,j}-\mu_j)^2 = 0$ hence $x_{i,j}=\mu_j$ for all $i$.

There is probably a cleaner proof of that last fact.

Comment: Ok, nice I think I understand. Yes it doesn't seem that clean, you are only using the diagonal of the zero map. $so \widehat{S} = U^T S U = \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i-\nu)(y_i-\nu)^T$. And you've shown by taking the diagonals of $\widehat{S}$ that the projected vectors  $y_{i}=\mathbf{U}^{T} \mathbf{x}_{i}=v$ for all i

Comment: I think we have to use only the diagonals, but there is probably a better way of doing so (probably the notation can be improved in the first place)